# Troubleshooting Internet On Debian

Tags: debian, networking, internet

My Debian 11 (Bullseye) computer uses a wired internet connection and I never had any problems.
But since a couple of days I have the issue that I have an internet connection for 10 seconds and then no internet connection for another 10 seconds.
How can I troubleshoot my wired internet connection on Debian?
Might be a problem with the router but I never had a similar problem.
Usually wired connections are very stable so I don't really know what to do.

`ping google.com` works for a while with 10-15ms for 64 bytes and then prints

```
Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what network configuration you use. You should edit your answer if you want to get more specific help. But here are some general network debugging tips.

Get your default gateway IP address with `ip route` and try to ping it directly. If you encounter the same problem:

1. Disable any VPN or proxy server configuration.
2. Check if `ip a` shows only one connected interface with a single IP address.
3. Make sure you are the only one in the network using this IP address. For debugging purposes, you can set up a static IP address out of the router's DHCP range. Make sure it's free first.

If the connection with your router is stable but you still have the same problem:

1. Make sure you use a stable DNS server. `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
2. Restart your modem/router so it can adapt to potential configuration changes from your ISP.

If the problem is persistent and happens on all devices in the network, you can consult your ISP. If it happens only on your computer, you can download and boot a live Linux distribution with a fresh network configuration to exclude any hardware malfunction.